# asp.net mvc 2 with dynamically generated views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to build an asp.net mvc 2 app for data entry. I want to generate the views on the forms dynamically so will be using htmlhelpers . What would be the most flexible option for the datasource ? so when i change the database i dont have to actually change the code at all(so i guess EF is not an option)? so no model/controller changes etc. Or i don't have a choice but changing the models in my code?

Comment: Are you referring to changes made to the data objects using LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Well by change database, i assume you mean change dbms, from sql server to oracle for example.

I doubt you'll find a solution to do this without any code changes at all, but you can make things a lot simpler by using interfaces for all you services.

For example

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
      ...
}
public class SqlServerDataRepository : IDataRepository
{
      ...
}
```

and for testing

```
public class MockRepository : IDataRepository
{
       ...
}
```

and later if you swith databases

```
public class OracleRepository : IDataRepository
{
       ...
}
```

This could then be used simple by referring to interfaces

```
public class MyService
{
       public MyService(IRepository repo)
       {
             //ctor
       {
}
```

And ideally injecting objects with Inversion of control, Ninject or structuremap for example.

Apologies if this is all already know to you and your looking for something different!

Comment: thanks for your feedback Paul! with 'changing the database' I meant changing the datamodel of it, so adding extra columns to a table for example?